# How to build a scope with a join in a Rails Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, scope

I want to recreate this SQL query `@user1.attended_events.where('day < ? ', Date.new + 5)` by using a scope.

So far, I know that I need to set `@prev_events = @user.previous` in the `UsersController`.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to write the `previous` scope for `User` model. I've given my best shot below:

Here is the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
..

    has_many :events, foreign_key: "creator_id" #instead of user_id, need to set own index

    has_many :event_relationships, foreign_key: "attendee_id"
    has_many :attended_events, through: :event_relationships, source: :attended_event
    has_secure_password

    ##How can I write this scope??
    scope :previous, joins(:event_relationships).where('attended_events.day < ? ', Date.new + 5)
..
end
```

I want to call the `previous` in the User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
..
  def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @prev_events = @user.previous
   @upcoming_events = @user.upcoming
  end
..
end
```

Here is the Event model for reference:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :past_events, -> { where('day < ? ', Date.new + 5) }
  scope :upcoming_events, -> { where('day >= ? ', Date.new + 5) }

  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User"

  has_many :event_relationships, foreign_key: "attended_event_id"
  has_many :attendees, through: :event_relationships, source: :attendee
  validates :description, presence: true

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use query methods inside a `lambda`:

```
scope :previous, -> { joins(:event_relationships).where(
  'attended_events.day < ? ', Date.today + 5) 
}
```

I assumed you wanted 5 days from today where you're doing `Date.new + 5`.

Comment: I'm still getting an error: `undefined method 'previous'` in the `Users#controller`. Any thoughts? Also, I'm working through a tutorial, so `Date.new + 5` works well.

Comment: Ah, you're calling it like an instance method.  Note that scopes are really class methods.  There are two options now: 1, pass user parameter to this scope and call it using `User.previous_events(@user)`, or 2, define an instance method.  Which one of these fulfils your requirement?

Comment: The second one...I think. Specifically, it wants me to use a scope and to call 'model methods': http://bit.ly/1hVnQbb

Comment: Model scopes can't be called using an instance. they behave like class methods.

Comment: Does that mean I have to call them like this...


 `def previous
    attended_events.where('day < ? ', Date.new + 5)
  end`

  `def upcoming
     attended_events.where('day >= ? ', Date.new + 5)
  end`

Comment: I realized that I creating a scope for a model method is probably not the best idea. Instead, I left the code a method in the model `User` class.